# Clusterized Docker and Managed by Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I am new in Docker, and I was wondering a question today.
I know there are spread and binpack strategies which are intends to balance the "work load".
But is there any way to provision the containers like the following topology by using Docker, Swarm?

[image]

Or should I customize the scheduler? Or is there any suitable cluster management tool? 
And is there any suggestion?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking or what the different colors mean in your diagram.  It's certainly possible to use docker swarm to provision docker containers on multiple physical hosts, but I'm not sure that's what you're asking about.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Let me make it more clear.
Firstly, assume there is no containers on any physical node.
Then request for four containers to provision, just like the greens.
According to the spread strategy, the containers would likely to be deployed on four physical nodes, and one for each.
But I am looking for another strategy, that can help me to deploy the four containers on maybe only two physical nodes and two for each physical node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Update**: This answer applies to the legacy docker/swarm and not to the new *Swarm mode* available since docker 1.12

You can achieve this with Swarm through `labels` when starting docker daemons on those racks/machines.

### Setup the Docker Daemons with labels

Assuming we have this topology:

```
rack1
  |___ node1

rack2
  |___ node2
  |___ node3
```

We can setup the docker daemons with custom labels to reflect this:

**Node 1 on Rack 1**

```
docker --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=server-cert.pem --tlskey=server-key.pem -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -d --label rack=rack1 --label machine=node1`
```

**Node 2 on Rack 2**

```
docker --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=server-cert.pem --tlskey=server-key.pem -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -d --label rack=rack2 --label machine=node2
```

**Node 3 on Rack 2**

```
docker --tlsverify --tlscacert=ca.pem --tlscert=server-cert.pem --tlskey=server-key.pem -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -d --label rack=rack2 --label machine=node3
```

### Using constraints

With Swarm you can then use **constraints** to pick up a location for your containers. In this example, we only use the subset of nodes on **Rack 1** to schedule our container:

```
docker run -d -P -e constraint:rack==rack1 --name web nginx
```

Providing that you have multiple nodes per rack (with `rack2` for example) you can also chain constraints. In the next example, we pin the container to `node3` which is located on `rack2`.

```
docker run -d -P -e constraint:rack==rack2 -e constraint:node==node3 --name web nginx
```